# Can you use a Tabi to dash through enemies/blocks?

Tags: terraria

I got a Tabi and saw that you can dash with it. I haven't seen any potential use, so I threw it away. Now, I need it to craft the Master Ninja Gear, but then I wondered: can you dash with the Tabi or Master Ninja Gear through blocks and enemies?

On the wiki pages for both I didn't find an answer. I need to know if I can use one of the items in Duke Fishron's fight to get through him and the sharknadoes he summons, since I don't have the Rod Of Discord.

Does the dash attack let you pass through enemies or blocks?

Comment: No, but you can use the dash to get away from him more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not dash through blocks/enemies. If you dash through an enemy, you will take damage, and knockback. If you attempt to dash through a wall, the wall will stop you.

Comment: The Master Ninja Gear does have the Black Belt's dodge though.